# How is DHT different than regular hash tables in context to data/node lookup?

Tags: hash-function, dc.distributed-comp

How is DHT different than regular hash tables in context to data/node lookup?

[This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.2405&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (introduction, 3rd paragraph) paper says:

> First, in addition to the insertion
>   and deletion of items, DHTs must support the insertion and deletion of
>   buckets: as machines join and leave
>   the network, items must be migrated to
>   other machines and the hash function
>   revised to reflect their new location.

This problem is also in Hashtables (for example, if you implement a hashtable in C using LinkedList and Array, then if the size of the array increased (new node added) then the data needs to be redistributed to achieve good load factor)

> Second, some kind of routing protocol
>   is usually necessary: since it is not
>   feasible in a P2P system for every
>   node to maintain up-to-date knowledge
>   of all other nodes in the system, an
>   item is looked up (or inserted) by
>   following a sequence of routing hops
>   through the peer-to-peer network.

Is this point talking about routing mechanism, if yes, then is this done is normal hashtable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question in the first sentence is a bit vague and open-ended. I'm guessing you want to know about routing and mutual node knowledge in the context of lookup.

Each node shouldn't have to know about every other node. Assuming a hash ring topology, the simplest approach is to have each node know about its two neighbors on the ring. This defines a circular linked list. Unfortunately, as with all linked lists, it only supports slow linear search. It's also very sensitive to node removal: if any two nodes go offline, it breaks the connectivity of the ring.

If you try to repair this idea by having nodes maintain knowledge of their longer-range relatives then you eventually wind up with the idea of a skip graph, a generalization of skip lists that can handle node disappearance robustly. Unlike skip lists they are not explicitly stratified, which is important due to the non-hierarchical peer-to-peer nature of the problem.